# Reading in data from file with java.util.Scanner

Tags: java

I have a file that contains data like:

```
Fantasy Football
Peyton Manning; 49
Eli Manning; 34
Colin Kaepernick; 33
```

I have read in the file using a `Scanner`, now I want to go through the data and pass it to this class.

```
class GBar {
    String text;
    int value;

    GBar(String t, int v) {
        text = t;
        value = v;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to pass the relevant info from the file to GBar.

Here is my code to read in the file

```
void ReadIn(String filename) {
    Scanner s = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
        s = new Scanner(fileInputStream);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }

    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = s.nextLine();
        fileDataArray.add(line);        
    }
    s.close();
}
```

Comment: You need to show your actual attempt, not just the data source and the data object.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class doc has some good examples.

Comment: You can read line for line... than use methods of String class methods and parse the number.

Comment: Ok I'll edit my post.

Comment: Your example code shows you reading the lines into an array of `String`s. I don't see any attempt to parse those strings into a `GBar`. If you don't have any idea how to get started, you may wish to reevaluate your participation in class or approach your instructor.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a good start. What you have done so far is to set up a way to read the file. You haven't actually read the lines in the file yet. After you create the `Scanner`, you need to loop until there are no more lines left. Check the `Scanner` [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29) for hints on how to do that. Then you can either process each line as you read it or store them off and process them in bulk once you've read them all. To process them you probably want to split the lines you get from the `Scanner` on the `;` character.

Comment: I've edited my "ReadIn"  My instructor was adding data to the GBar class manually like this garr.add(new GBar("Bubba", 320));

I'm not sure how to go through my data and pass it to GBar.

Comment: Ok, so your `ReadIn` method fills `fileDataArray` with one entry for each line. All you have to do now is loop through that array, parse the `text` and `value` parts out of each line (check out the methods available on the `String` class, specifically the `split` method), and use those values to create your `GBar` objects.